# Do I need to leave extra time at LGA due to Covid?

Tags: lga, southwest-airlines

I will be flying Southwest out of LaGuardia airport on a weekday morning. I have not flown since the pandemic hit.  Do I need to plan to have more time at LGA than in pre-covid times?
Thanks.

Comment: This depends on where you are coming from to LGA. Much of NYC car traffic is back to pre-covid levels. Since you are going on a weekday morning plan for morning rush hour if you are planning to take a car/taxi/uber/lyft.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to plan to have more time at LGA than in pre-covid times?

Not for a domestic flight (which I think is true for all Southwest flights from LGA).

Domestic travel has no extra checks for Covid tests, entry restrictions, etc. Airports are still significantly below capacity and security tends to be well staffed. Traffic is picking up but in general things go still faster than pre-pandemic.

Comment: Does the massive construction project have any bearing on this?